# suPHP : proper use of the chroot feature

Tags: apache-2.2, chroot, suphp

I started using suPHP recently, and I'm spending an amazing amount of time debugging the configurations and different compile options to get something that *actually works*. I've tried contacting the development team through their mailing list, but it's obviously made of ghosts...

I am trying to use the `chroot` parameter, but it trigger a 500 Internal Error which I just can't solve.

I am using DBD MySQL for the DocumentRoot definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams <params>
    DBDocRoot "SELECT document_root FROM domains WHERE name=%s" HOSTNAME

    suPHP_Engine on
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php
</VirtualHost>
```

Once the VirtualHost has set the DocumentRoot, suPHP is supposed to apply an additional chroot. See the relevant section of my `/etc/suphp.conf` below:

```
docroot=${HOME}
chroot=${HOME}

allow_file_group_writeable=false
allow_file_others_writeable=false
allow_directory_group_writeable=false
allow_directory_others_writeable=false
check_vhost_docroot=false
```

The `chroot` parameters couldn't possibly be simpler, yet suPHP spits:

```
Caused by SystemException in API_Linux.cpp:465: chdir() failed: No such file or directory
```

... when I make a request to a PHP script. The `suphp` log does not contain any information, this line comes from the Apache error log.

Does *anyone* on Earth actually now how to setup this horrible chroot feature? I've been through countless forums and mails from the listing, but no-one has yet given a proper answer (even though this feature has been patched an unbelievable number of times). Or maybe I should switch to suExec, hoping it'll offer more satisfying results...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you do not understand how chroot works. Once you chroot into /home/user, that's the new root and the paths are "relative" to it. So, if you have your files in /home/user/public_html and want to chroot to /home/user then the chdir should actually be /public_html and the fastcgi document root would be the same (/public_html).

It is technically impossible for suPHP to run chroot at a farther point in the way to launching the process.

Comment: I do understand how chroot works. suPHP designers obviously don't. `chdir` is a call made by suPHP, not my script. It calls it before chrooting. I've spotted two errors in `API_Linux.cpp`. suPHP throws this error, but the `chroot` actually happens. However, due to design errors, many other things seem to fail afterwards.

Comment: Actually you are not right. The chdir is indeed made by suPHP but AFTER chroot. Chroot is being done at the initialization of suPHP while chdir is being done when executing a script, on a per script launch basis. So chdir is executed inside the chroot.

Comment: The implementation of the `chroot` feature makes suPHP unable to find `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` (since it's already locked into the user's home). It's obviously triggered to early... The `chroot` call is supposed to be made *at script execution*, not earlier. Because of this, I just can't find a way to configure it correctly. I can't actually place a copy of php5-cgi into each user home, that'd be ridiculous.

Comment: I am sorry but I will have to flag your answer and comments as you do not understand how it works. If you want it to work that way, it means that the already launched binary would require to chroot by its own. You need to build a chroot environment with all the libraries and binaries in order to run PHP inside chroot with suPHP. Not to mention that you downvoted an absolutely correct answer.

Comment: suPHP is supposed to chroot into home directories. If I follow your reasoning, that means that each home directory has to become a chroot environment, that is, each must contain every single PHP binary. Is that the way you hear it?

Comment: No, you can achieve this using bind mounts. You only need one environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15814/discussion-between-florin-asavoaie-and-john-wh-smith).